# XXDMC3 update for Galaxy Note 2

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note-2

What exactly does it fix? By googling I got to know that it fixes some bug related to the lock screen. Do any one know of that bug. Got to know regarding this as I got a notification regarding software update in the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update is just a bug fix update, no new features. The lock screen bug that you mentioned allowed bypassing the lock screen for a short amount of time, details can be found for example on [TheVerge](http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/20/4127438/galaxy-note-ii-security-flaw-disables-lockscreen-gives-complete-access) or [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-lock-screen-bypassed-entirely-clever-meticulous-trickery).